# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SocialMenu`. (React.js in a Meteor.js app)

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am trying to set up a dynamic menu in my Meteor.js app using react.js.  Everytime I run this, I get the "key" error.  What is going on?

SocialMenu.jsx:

```
SocialMenu = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { focused: 0 };
    },

    clicked: function(index){

        // The click handler will update the state with
        // the index of the focused menu entry

        this.setState({focused: index});
    },

    render: function() {

        // Here we will read the items property, which was passed
        // as an attribute when the component was created

        var self = this;

        // The map method will loop over the array of menu entries,
        // and will return a new array with <li> elements.

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){

                    var style = '';

                    if(self.state.focused == index){
                        style = 'focused';
                    }

                    // Notice the use of the bind() method. It makes the
                    // index available to the clicked function:

                    return <li className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

                }) }

                </ul>

                <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p>
            </div>
        );

    }
});
```

myapp.jsx:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // Use Meteor.startup to render the component after the page is ready
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
    ReactDOM.render(
    <SocialMenu items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
    document.getElementById('socialmenu')
    );
  });
}
```

Also, as far as best practices, should I run the render function for each of my React Classes in the startup function?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What react is complaining is that you did not specify a key for the children, so please create a unique key, the key should be the same if the object is the same:

```
<li key={uniqueKey} className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to React, what do I put in the uniqueKey variable?  And where?

Comment: in your map function you try something like: 

                    return <li key={index} className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

Comment: your example does have a key, it's the {index}, which works.  Thank you.

Comment: yes, but you can also delete it and it still works :).

Comment: but yes, you will get a warning otherwise

Comment: If you render a bunch of items in a list and one of them changes, React is going to have to do a bunch of re-rendering since it can't tell which list item is which; however, if you put a unique `key` on each of them, it can only update the one(s) it needs to. It'll work fine otherwise but will be less performant on large lists. Hope this helps! (For the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)